# Selenium - finding an Elements class name

Tags: eclipse, selenium

Good Afternoon, I am currently trying to teach myself Selenium Webdriver using the Eclipse IDE and Java Language. So i have the following element that i have found by its ID

```
<button role="tab" id="tabs-id_1-link-1" class="c-tabs__link is-active" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tabs-id_1-article-1">**</button>
```

i'm pretty new to selenium but so far i have used this to find the element,

```
WebElement Currentbilltab = driver.findElement(By.id("tabs-id_1-link-1"));
```

but i would then like to find out if the class of this Element contains the word active. What would be the best way to do this? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Mention code clearly.

Answer (score 0):

you can get any attribute of element using following API

```
WebElement.getAttribute("attribute");
```

for your case

```
Currentbilltab.getAttribute("class");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code. It will identify the text for you on that element and then print it:-

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='tabs-id_1-link-1']")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

If you want to get any attribute value then use :-

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("tabs-id_1-link-1")).getAttribute("class");
System.out.println(text);
```

In above code the value of class will be print out

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `class` attribute of the element with `id` as `tabs-id_1-link-1` you can use the following code block:

```
//Store the WebElement
WebElement Currentbilltab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='tabs-id_1-link-1']"));

//Retrieve the class attribute of the WebElement in a String
String element_class = Currentbilltab.getAttribute("class");

//Print the String which contains the class attribute of the WebElement
System.out.println("Class name of the element is: "+element_class);
```